# Getting odd ACPI bios error when installing Ubuntu to surface laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb-installation

I've been attempting to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 to my surface laptop 4, but I keep getting this strange error. It's the AMD version, by the way. I'm sure that's important somehow. Apologies, I'm somewhat of a newbie to all of this. Picture of the error:

[image: picture of the error]

Comment: Re: "*I'm sure that's important somehow.*", not necessarily ... If your system boots and runs without issues, then you can safely ignore those.

Comment: That's the problem, it doesn't boot into ubuntu, and this error is on initial install.

Comment: Try with 23.10. Sometimes this happens due to kernels bugs which may have been fixed in a more recent kernel.

Comment: I'll go ahead and give it a shot, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, it's still giving the same error. Any ideas or am I out of options?